# Qt drag/drop: cannot move when copy is enabled (Ubuntu Gnome)

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, drag-and-drop, gnome

I'm implementing a view and a model where I want to support both moving items internally (by dragging), and copying items (by pressing Ctrl while dragging). I've done everything I need to do according to the instructions. I've set up the mime functions, I've implemented removeRows(), and flags(). The problem is when I drag, it defaults to a copy operation (I get the arrow cursor with a plus sign, and it indeed copies the item by creating a new one in the model).

The only difference I can see is this: If I return only Qt::MoveAction in supportedDropActions(), it only moves. If I return (Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction), it only copies.

Any ideas? I want it to work like files in Nautilus (Gnome) or Windows file Explorer: drag moves icons around, ctrl+drag copies them.

Comment: The same problem occurs on Windows, but with `Qt::MoveAction` being the preferred choice.

Comment: I can post some example code to demonstrate the problem, if anyone would like.

Comment: Since this didn't answer my question in the end, who feels they deserve the bounty?

Comment: I'm the one who added setDefaultDropAction() to QAbstractItemView in Qt 4.7, does that mean I deserve the bounty? :-)

Comment: David, I'd consider giving you the bounty, but I didn't post it, I didn't even know about it, and it looks like it ended a month after it was posted.  Anyway, thanks for your contributions to Qt and KDE! (On a side note, it still bugs me--there are *SIX* (6) properties related to drag/drop for an item view! Six! acceptDrops, showDropIndicator, dragEnabled, dragDropOverwriteMode, dragDropMode, and your defaultDropAction. Then of course there's a litany of code to write to do the MIME type, work with removeRows(), flags()--like I said I love Qt but wow, drag/drop is complicated!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I didn't follow up by answering this question when I found what I was doing wrong. The code that messed me up was in `QAbstractItemView::startDrag()`:

```
if (d->defaultDropAction != Qt::IgnoreAction && (supportedActions & d->defaultDropAction))
        defaultDropAction = d->defaultDropAction;
    else if (supportedActions & Qt::CopyAction && dragDropMode() != QAbstractItemView::InternalMove)
        defaultDropAction = Qt::CopyAction;
```

The problem is I wasn't setting the **defaultDropAction** property on the widget as in `setDefaultDropAction( Qt::MoveAction );`  Therefore startDrag() was defaulting to CopyAction. If the defaultDropAction is Qt::MoveAction, then you can use the keyboard Ctrl to switch a drag in progress to a copy action, which is my desired behavior.

I love Qt, but there sure are a lot of confusing and somewhat intertwined properties related to drag/drop. It's easy to to not get the right combination of properties.

Bottom line: make sure to set the **defaultDropAction** to **Qt::MoveAction**.

Comment: Just to give a little more information, the properties I had to change on the listView are as follows: acceptDrops: true, dragEnabled: true, defaultDropAction: MoveAction (this was the big one!), selectionMode: ExtendedSelection (also an expected Windows Explorer behavior but not the default for QListView). Also in the model: setSupportedDragActions( Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction );, return Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction in MyModel::Model::supportedDropActions(), add Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled to MyModel::flags(), implement MyModel::mimeTypes(), mimeData(), and dropMimeData. Hope that helps!

Comment: This means the bug I'm experiencing is actually different from the one you experienced. It's looking like a Qt bug on Windows.

Comment: D K, I'm curious--is it a Qt SDK (Creator) which is *usually* mingw based, or is it Qt compiled with Visual Studio (which is WinAPI based?). Also, my issue was, with Copy as the default behavior, I could not achieve Move at all, because there's no keyboard modifier to change Copy to Move. You say you're having a problem with Move--so can you not hold Ctrl and change it to Copy?

Comment: After a bit more experimentation, it seems that Qt is forcing the external drop target decide what it wants to do with the file. If I drag the file to anywhere in explorer, it forces a `Qt::TargetMoveAction`, but if I drag it on to Chromium for example, it forces a `Qt::CopyAction`. Keyboard modifiers do work, but ideally, they shouldn't be necessary to achieve the correct drop action. I am using `PySide`, which I believe would be based on mingw.

Comment: That does seem strange--I'm not sure why a drop target gets to decide (at least for a default) if the source should keep its copy (as in a CopyAction) or remove it (as in a MoveAction). It seems like that wouldn't make any difference to the drop target.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to drag and drop, but on Windows when using drag&drop with files/folders the default is to Move when the target and source root (C:, D:, etc) directories are the same and to Copy when they are different. Since only the drop target knows its own root directory, perhaps that's coming into play?

Answer (score 0):

what if you try this way
First write a keyPressEvent and set whether ctrl key is pressed or not
    '

```
keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
    {
        if(e->key() == Qt::Key_Control)
            bControlKeyPressed = true;
    }
    keyReleaseEvent (QKeyEvent *e)
    {
       if(e->key() == Qt::Key_Control)
          bControlKeyPressed = false;
    }
```

And in mouse pressEvent check whether ctrl key is pressed

```
`mousePressEvent()
{ 
  if (bControlKeyPressed) 
    //enable Qt::CopyAction 
else 
    //enable  Qt::MoveAction 
}`
```

Comment: An answer as simple as this would be ideal, but Ubuntu/Windows just ignores the specified action (and the default action too).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

enable the copy action. Then listen to drap&drop signals or override virtual methods (or whatever Qt offers, I didn't check) and if the action you meant is move, remove the row "manually". When a drop is made, save the action you prefer.

If there's no way to determine the desired action from Qt data, check the Ctrl key status and save a boolean saying whether it's copy or move. Now, when Qt signals something was dropped, check the action you chose, and delete the moved row by yourself.

(I personally use gtkmm, where copy-if-Ctrl-is-pressed works pefectly)

Comment: This solution does somewhat work, but has two problems: a) The drag icon is incorrect. b) If several items are selected, dragging them between themselves deletes some and copies others.

Comment: Then I see two options for you. 1) The just-get-rid-of-it approach: Set the icon manually. For multiple selection, handle the drop by yourself. Decide how to move/copy each node. It may be complicated, depending on how Qt lets you access the drag&drop data... 2) the serious engineer approach: find out why this don't work like they should. Qt is Free software, so if there's a bug, investigate the see if it can be solved. Thus you make a contribution to all users of Qt and any application written with Qt. And no workarounds will ever be needed.

Comment: If there's a problem with Windows internals, the best you can do is send them an e-mail. Windows is proprietary software so I regard it as their problem, not mine or yours, if D&D doesn't work like it should. Or add a temporary workaround in your code,  just for Windows